# Disk has 73 bad sectors - should I be worried?

Tags: hard-drive, hardware-failure, ubuntu-14.04

I'm using Ubuntu 14.04.3 LTS and the standard "Disks" application says "Disk is OK, 73 bad sectors (30° C / 86° F)".
The temperature is a bit high because that just recently I copied a lot of data (approx. 2GB) from the disk (many *read* operations) for backup.

The disk model is `WDC WD5000AAKS-22V1A0`.

Does this problem of sectors indicate that probably the disk will completely fail in the very near future?

Comment: Hard to be sure. Just in case, make sure that your backups (which you certainly have) are up-to-date and complete.

Comment: Temperatures of 30°C should not be a problem, that's quite normal. 73 bad sectors are no problem as well, but like sleske says, do your backups and watch over that, too. If the damaged sector count raises quickly, you should get a new hard drive. If not, you have no problem.

Comment: What are the full SMART values?

Answer (score 2):

It doesn't necessarily mean that your HD is about to fail. It might just be that these sectors are bad, and the operating system will mark them as unusable (i.e., will avoid reading/writing from them). However, if you had data on them you probably lost them.

There's a link that explains that deeply: [Bad Sectors Explained: Why Hard Drives Get Bad Sectors and What You Can Do About It](http://www.howtogeek.com/173463/bad-sectors-explained-why-hard-drives-get-bad-sectors-and-what-you-can-do-about-it/)

I'd monitor the disk for some amount of time, if it goes worse, I'd replace the disk as soon as possible. In any case, if you haven't yet, backup *all* your data and keep it up to date.